# Why can't I call methods on my Mail::Sender object?

Tags: perl, mail-sender

I have this simple part of the program that should send an email to a specified user.
But it has an error that says "Can't call method "MailMsg" on an undefined value"

```
 if ($sender->MailMsg({smtp => 'mail.myISP.com',
   from => 'suezy.ourdomainhere.com',
   to =>'sample@domainhere.com',
   subject => 'this is a test',
   msg => "testing....\n?"}) < 0) 
 {
  die "$Mail::Sender::Error\n";
 }
   print "Successfully sent."
```

Something wrong? Can anyone give me suggestions please?
Is it possible that I wasn't able to install the package properly?

Comment: Show us where you construct `$sender`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `$sender` is not defined - i.e. the variable has no value in it.

Have you created a Sender object doing something like the following:

```
$sender = new Mail::Sender
  {smtp => 'mail.yourdomain.com', from => 'your@address.com'};
```